# Access AutoComplete inside Fragment of Tab Layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, autocompletetextview, android-tabs

Following is my onCreate code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.i(TAG, "Inside Base Drawer...");

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager){

            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab){
                tabPosition = tab.getPosition();
            }
        });

    }
```

And following is my FragmentPageAdapter, for sliding tab layouts

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                Tab1Fragment tab1 = new Tab1Fragment();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                Tab1Fragment tab2 = new Tab2Fragment();
                return tab2;
            case 2:
                Tab1Fragment tab3 = new Tab3Fragment();
                return tab3;
            default:
                return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Following is the tabFragment code:

```
public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_activity_sheet_details_tab1, viewGroup, false);
    }
}
```

I have a custom autocompleteTextView inside the tab layout (**tab_activity_sheet_details_tab1**)
Following is the code for the same:

```
<com.example.user.package.TabLayoutActivity.AutoCompleteAdapter.HistoryAutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/history_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
            android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi|actionSearch"/>
```

However, I'm not being able to access this element from TabLayoutActivity. What is the best way to access this after the fragment view is inflated? 
And do note that there are similar items in all the three Tab Layouts.
Is there a need of a separate adapter holding all the three fragment layouts and access them? If so, from which lifecycle element can I access them?
P.S.: I'm looking for a non-adapter access to fragments, if possible (possibly by "layout id")?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would expose the view to the outside world:

```
public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment {
    View mView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_activity_sheet_details_tab1, viewGroup, false);
        return mView;
    }

    public HistoryAutoCompleteTextView getTextView() {
      return (HistoryAutoCompleteTextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.history_text);
    }
}
```

Then you can get it from the fragment:

```
   textView = ((Tab1Fragment)fragment).getTextView()
```

But from a software design point of view, you should probably not do that and consider instead managing this view entirely in the Fragment and only expose the data collected.

Comment: In that case do you think, the right thing to do is to access the elements inside fragment from onActivityCreated() and return the data to activity at onStop()? Both of these functions would reside inside Tab1Fragments class?

Comment: Yes, kind of. Adding a setData(MyData data) and getData() methods to the Tab1Fragment class would allow you to load the data into and retrieve the modified data from the fragment. Those methods would take care of loading the data into the UI elements like your text fields, and retrieving it from them. Then, in your activity, you need to use those methods on the fragment at the time it is presented (setData) and before it is removed (getData).

Comment: Thank you. Can you just provide a small help. Where in the Activity Class should I put the setdata and getdata? It seems  the only place where the Fragment object is accessible is inside the SectionsPagerAdapter in Activity class. What I'm doing is defining them as public variables inside activity class. Can I set & get data from there directly? How can I set data even when the layout isn't layout isn't inflated?

Comment: The onAttachFragment() method of the activity would be one option. The Fragment's UI is not created at the time it is called, so the setData() method would only store the given data in the Fragment, but then you can use the data in the onCreateView() method of the Fragment to load the data into the UI.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I shall check the details and get back only after that